# Is it possible to skip the nursery?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

If I know a certain value is likely to survive its first encounter with the garbage collector, is there some way to let GHC know, so it can just allocate it directly somewhere outside the nursery? For instance, if I'm building up a large structure out of a bunch of smaller pieces, I know each piece will last at least until the whole structure is complete.

Comment: As a little meta-comment: I hate this sort of question, because you always think, "No, there's no way." but the immediate thought after that is, "Well, I'm sure I don't know *everything* about the compiler (maybe only one or two people do), and since it's open source of course there's a way to do anything computable, but... that's not really an answer...". Does anybody have constructive ways to answer this kind of question?

Comment: This optimization is called "[pretenuring](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/p.html#term-premature-tenuring)" - there's been some research into it, but I don't believe that it's been incorporated into any mainstream compiler / runtime.

Comment: @DanielWagner, aside from any features I might have missed, I wondered if there might be some tricky way to exploit GHC's mechanisms for dealing with large and/or foreign objects. I couldn't immediately see such a thing, but I'm *really* not familiar with those systems.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I believe "premature tenuring" (what you linked to) describes the opposite, a mechanism of preventing short-lived objects from leaving the nursery when they first encounter the GC by avoiding any encounter with the GC. This question is asking for a mechanism for long-lived objects to start promoted so that the first encounter with the GC doesn't need to promote them.

Comment: @Cirdec The problem is that the definition I linked to describes pretenuring as a being a problem (short-lived objects being promoted too soon), not as an optimization (long-lived objects being promoted early).  [This](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~moss/papers/oopsla-2001-pretenure.pdf) is a paper that describes it as being an optimization, also [this paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/speedway/DaCapo/papers/toplas-pretenure.pdf), however the memorymanagement.org link is the only definition I could find that wasn't embedded in a paper

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In [the GHC garbage collector](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC) there are no hooks for hinting at the generation an object should be allocated to. However, you might be able to exploit the operational behavior in a couple of ways:

- depending on the data type, you may be able to exploit [the pinned object regio](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/Pinned)n to bypass the generational stages altogether.
- exploit [eager promotion](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/EagerPromotion) by ensuring your long lived object is pointed out by something itself long lived...
- make the data into [a CAF](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/CAFs) and bypass dynamic allocation altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I'm doing is too polymorphic to use pinning, and making the data into a CAF isn't generally an option. If you edit your answer to explain a little more how I might trick eager promotion, I'll happily accept this answer. Note: my current use-case is reducing the GC time for `Data.Sequence.fromList`, which is somewhat absurdly high.